# multiple column selection with aggregate function in LINQ dictionary

Tags: c#-3.0

I was unable to cope with converting this Sql Query to Linq Expression

SELECT IdVehicle, 
       AVG(Kilometers)
FROM [Fuel]
GROUP BY IdVehicle, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Fuel.Time, 102)

Rows are inserted into this table when someone fills fuel into vehicle. Kilometers are read from tachograph. It's possible to fill fuel twice a day so I need average value. 
Ideally, LINQ result would be Dictionary.

I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like these you might wanna try LinqPad ([www.linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net)). This great tool lets you test and analyze both SQL statements and Linq expressions.